# Prevent dropdown from being opened if certain condition is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am using selectize.js to provide some suggestions while the user enters a query in a textbox. However, I would like to prevent the dropdown from being opened if certain conditions are not met. I'm aware of the [`onDropdownOpen`](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#callbacks) callback, but it seems that the event can't be stopped from there. The following workaround doesn't work either.

```
onDropdownOpen: function($dropdown) {
    // [Test some variables here]
    $dropdown.collapse();
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `if(condition) return false;`?

Comment: A good question to ask the selectize.js authors.

Comment: @connexo Yes, nothing happens.

Comment: Even if you put that on the `onclick` handler on the element?

Comment: @connexo The dropdown shows suggestions while the user types, how is `onclick` related?

Comment: I think making the adjustment to put it on the matching handler for your triggering event shouldn't be too hard for you. Be it `onkeydown`, `onweatherchange` or whatever.

Comment: @connexo That's ok, maybe I was missing something. However, `onkeydown` doesn't mean the dropdown was opened...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I tried that seems to be working
https://plnkr.co/edit/DifihIuXoGkMxfdEht9L?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#input-tags').selectize({
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    create: function(input) {
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    },
    onDropdownOpen: function(){
      // you can add your logic here to conditionally close the drop down
      this.close(); 
      // I had to set it to false because when it is true, this will run into infinite loop since while the input is in focus, it will trigger to open the drop down.
      this.settings.openOnFocus = false;
    }
});
});
```